# El destinatario no entendio el encabezado 'Security' Servicio Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, soap, web.config

estoy consumiendo un servicio web pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> El destinatario de este mensaje no entendió el encabezado 'Security'
>   del espacio de nombres
>   'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd',
>   por lo que el mensaje no se procesó.
>
> Este error suele indicar que el remitente del mensaje habilitó un
>   protocolo de comunicación que el destinatario no puede procesar.
>   Asegúrese de que la configuración del enlace del cliente es coherente
>   con el enlace del servicio.

Asi tengo la configuracion:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="facturaElectronicaPortNameSoap11" closeTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="facturaElectronicaPortNameSoap11"
        contract="ServiceFacturacionDian.facturaElectronicaPortName"
        name="facturaElectronicaPortNameSoap11" >
    <headers xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" >
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
          <wsse:Username>0ef3-77-4e76-ttr5f03</wsse:Username>
          <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">h8548fddfa55e3e2</wsse:Password>
          <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">kWkpK8Ckk9eIoqGIA5r//Q==</wsse:Nonce>
          <wsse:Created>2014-10-13T14:53:05.089Z</wsse:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
    </headers>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Asi estoy consumiendo el servicio:

```
facturaElectronicaPortNameClient factura = new facturaElectronicaPortNameClient();
EnvioFacturaElectronica envio = new EnvioFacturaElectronica();
envio.NIT = "905485476";
          envio.InvoiceNumber = "990000005";
          envio.IssueDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-06-26T00:00:00");
          envio.Document = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\face_f09001605360000000001.xml");
peticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1 = envio;
           respuesta.EnvioFacturaElectronicaRespuesta1 = factura.EnvioFacturaElectronica(peticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1);
```

Comment: Pregunta duplicada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118409/problema-con-wss-security-no-puedo-leer-el-request-de-un-ws